# Set OpenGL window hints in Gloss

Tags: haskell, opengl, gloss

I am looking into the [gloss](http://gloss.ouroborus.net/) library and as any sane person I am quite irritated by the lack of anti-aliasing. I know some OpenGL window hints that help enabling anti-aliasing, especially the `GL.lineSmooth` hint. However looking through the Gloss haddock docs there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to set OpenGL hints. So how would I go forward doing this?

Comment: You might have a look at the [`gl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gl) library - supposedly it is a _complete_ set of OpenGL raw bindings.

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but not how to change the Gloss OpenGL initialization code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best I can figure out...

`gloss` abstracts graphics backends via the `class Backend` type class, and there are two instances defined:

```
instance Backend GLFWState
instance Backend GLUTState
```

Which one is used is controlled at compile time via the `WITHGLUT` and `WITHGLFW` CPP macros.

This explains why gloss doesn't provide functions to customize the GL setup - as far as it is concerned the backend is abstract.

The initialization code for the GLUT backend is in the `initializeGLUT` function in Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/GLUT.hs

Perhaps you can modify that routine to set up GLUT they way you want to obtain a custom version of gloss.

Comment: Heh. Here we have a library that abstracts out two other libraries whose only purpose is to abstract out several other libraries.

Comment: Yes, the simplest option seems like to modify the `initialize` function and compile gloss manually. I will give it a try when I get home.